# jquery - retrieving .data() values whose label contains a given string

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-caching

I'm using jquery's .data() function to cache a series of values on the document.body object. This caching is done dynamically using an .each() function:

```
$('foo').each(function(){
 var bar = $('foo').attr('id');
 var myVal = $('foo').val();
 $.data(document.body, 'docDepth-' + bar, myVal);    
});
```

Later on I want to retrieve this set of data pairs. My problem is, though, that I don't know how to retrieve them since (a) I don't know how many data pairs will be attached to document.body, and (b) I don't know what all the possible labels will be for the data pairs.

What I need to be able to do is look through the stored data pairs on document.body, find those whose label contains the string "docDepth", and then return them as an array. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the data stored on an element by using `var d = $('element').data();`

It will return the entire data object, which you can then iterate through to find key value pairs that you need.

```
for (var i in d)
{
  var v = d[i];
  console.log('key:', i, 'value:', v);
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: OK, I'm still having trouble figuring out how to filter the contents of d and select only the key value pairs whose key contains a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just caching you can do so much cheaper using your own object directly, like this:

```
var cache = {};
$('foo').each(function(){
  cache[this.id] = $(this).val();
});
```

Since we're in an object just for this, no need for the prefix overhead.  Then to iterate over them later use a `for..in` loop for [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), like this:

```
$.each(cache, function(key, value) {
  //use key, value here
});
```